# Truncating 2 Strings and combined into smaller String

Tags: string, vb.net, truncate

So, I have two strings that are each a max length of 100.

```
 Dim a as String ''has a max length of 100
 Dim b as String ''has a max length of 100
```

These two strings need to be truncated and combined into a new string.

```
 Dim c as String 'has a max length of 100
```

I need to be able to truncate each string appropriately so that I can get string c as close to 100.  I was going to do a bunch of statements by 25 to truncate each one.

```
 if a.length = 100 and b.length =0 then
     return a
 else if a.length = 100 andalso b.length <= 25 then
     return a.truncate(75) & b
 else if a.length = 100 andalso b.length <= 50 then
     return a.truncate(50) & b
 else if....
```

and so one to hit all the scenarios...

I feel like there is a better way to do this and a more efficient way so that i may not hit scenarios like a.length = 100 and b.length = 51.  I would be truncating more characters then needed.

Any suggestions??  Please critique me as needed.

EDIT, This is vb.Net..not C# (I'm between Projects) Sorry!

The reason i do not want to just add them together and truncate them is because if both strings are 100 in length, it will completely truncate off the second string.  If they are both 100 then I would want to truncate string a to 50 in length and string b to 50 in length so when they are combined they are 100 total.  In other words I need some text from both strings.

Comment: For starters, that not c# code (as per title and tag)

Comment: Why do you tag your question with both vb.net and c# when it appears that it only concerns vb.net?

Comment: Your logic is unclear. Just add them together and truncate them if longer than 100 seems to be the obvious choice... if you don't want that, you need to describe what you *want*.

Comment: What is your rule? Figure out the formula f() which will work with any lengths of a and b such that c = f(a, b). It seems like you don't have that rule, which should be your starting point, and is the most difficult part of your question. The code used to implement it is mostly trivial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the total length of the strings is greater than the limit then you could take a fraction of each in proportion to their lengths:

```
Module Module1

    Function CombineWithLengthConstraint(a As String, b As String, totalLength As Integer) As String

        ' trivial case 1:
        If totalLength < 1 Then
            Return String.Empty
        End If

        Dim aLen = Len(a)
        Dim bLen = Len(b)

        ' trivial case 2:
        If aLen + bLen <= totalLength Then
            Return a & b
        End If

        ' impossible-to-satisfy-equably case:
        If totalLength = 1 Then
            If aLen > 0 Then
                Return a.Substring(0, 1)
            ElseIf bLen > 0 Then
                Return b.Substring(0, 1)
            Else
                Return String.Empty
            End If
        End If

        ' aportion the lengths of the strings to be taken in the ratio of their lengths:
        Dim aFrac = CInt(Math.Round(aLen / (aLen + bLen) * totalLength, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero))
        Dim bFrac = CInt(Math.Round(bLen / (aLen + bLen) * totalLength, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero))

        ' ensure there is at least one character from each string...
        If aFrac = 0 Then
            aFrac = 1
            bFrac -= 1
        End If
        If bFrac = 0 Then
            bFrac = 1
            aFrac -= 1
        End If

        Dim aPart = a.Substring(0, aFrac)
        Dim bPart = b.Substring(0, bFrac)

        Return aPart & bPart

    End Function

    Sub Main()

        Dim a = New String("A"c, 10)
        Dim b = New String("b"c, 40)
        Dim c = CombineWithLengthConstraint(a, b, 10)

        Console.WriteLine(c)
        Console.WriteLine(Len(c))

        Console.ReadLine()

    End Sub

End Module
```

Outputs:

> AAbbbbbbbb
>   10

As you can see, the first string, which was 1/5 of the total number of characters, ended up contributing 1/5 of the result.

The VB.NET [`Len`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.strings.len?view=netframework-4.7.1#Microsoft_VisualBasic_Strings_Len_System_String_) function gives 0 if its argument is Nothing.

I tested it as working with all lengths from 0 to 100 of both strings being combined into one string of length 100 just in case I had made a mistake with the rounding or anything.

Of course, you could return, say, the ending part of string b instead of the starting part if that made sense in the particular application.

Comment: We must have been typing our answers at the same time.  We had the same idea, but yours accounts for rounding better and makes sure you get at least one character from each string.  Have an upvote, sir.

Comment: @dwilliss Thanks! I think I accounted for all the possible edge cases, but I only tested it completely for a total length of 100. I refrained from extending it to work for an arbitrary number of strings, but you can see how that *could* be done.

Answer (score 1):

Although not *exactly* what you asked for, here's another option...

```
Public Function WeirdConcatinate(a As String, b As String) As String
    Dim totalLen = a.Length + b.Length
    If totalLen > 100 Then
        Dim aLen = 100 * a.Length \ totalLen
        Dim bLen = 100 - aLen
        Return a.Remove(aLen) & b.Remove(bLen)
    Else
        Return a & b
    End If
End Function
```

This will give you a number of characters from each string (approximately) proportional to how long they are compared to each other.  If both strings are the same length, you'll get 50 from each.  If a.Length = 100 and b.Length = 50, you'll end up with 66 from a and 34 from b.

Answer (score 0):

Truncate them after concatenating them, then:

```
Dim c = a & b
If c.Length > 100 Then c = c.Remove(100)
```

If you want to preserve as much as possible of the start of each string:

```
Dim c = ""
If(a.Length > 50 AndAlso b.Length < 50)
  c = a.Remove(100 - b.Length) & b
Else If a.Length > 50 AndAlso b.Length > 50
  c= a.Remove(50) & b.Remove(50) 
Else 
  c = a & b
End if

If c.Length > 100 Then c = c.Remove(100)
```

Comment: So is there a clean way to do this for all numbers? What if a.length = 72 and b.length = 64.  How would you know to dynamically remove 22 characters from string a and 14 characters from string b so when you combined it is 100? or if a.length is 78 and b.length is 25, to only remove 3 from a and o from b?  Getting my drift?

Answer (score 0):

As with some other answers, the algorithm is open to interpretation. My method takes from each string until 100 total characters are taken or the string runs out of characters.

```
Private Function concat(a As String, b As String, length As Integer) As String
    Dim ca As New System.Text.StringBuilder()
    Dim cb As New System.Text.StringBuilder()
    For i As Integer = 0 To length - 1
        ca.Append(If(i >= a.Length, "", a(i)))
        cb.Append(If(i >= b.Length, "", b(i)))
        If ca.Length + cb.Length >= length Then Exit For
    Next
    Return (ca.ToString() & cb.ToString() & New String(" "c, 100)).Substring(0, length)
End Function

Sub Main()
    Dim a As String = New String("a"c, 0)
    Dim b As String = New String("b"c, 5)
    Dim c As String = concat(a, b, 100)
    Console.WriteLine($"'{c}'")
End Sub
```

> 'bbbbb                                                                                               '

(padded to 100 characters, doesn't render in block quote)

```
Dim a As String = New String("a"c, 30)
Dim b As String = New String("b"c, 90)
```

> 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb'

```
Dim a As String = New String("a"c, 72)
Dim b As String = New String("b"c, 64)
```

> 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb'

(your example in a comment. 72 >> 50, 64 >> 50)